# Compare two columns and highlight any difference

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare two columns and highlight any differences.

The columns are not next to each other.

```vb
Sub ColumnCompare()

Dim DerLigA As Long, DerLigB As Long, i As Long, j As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Sheet1")

    DerLigA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    DerLigB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To DerLigA
        For j = 2 To DerLigB
            If .Range("A" & i) = .Range("E" & j) Then
                .Range("E" & j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You'll have to think about what exactly you want to color. Right now it's in mid air. Assign it to a Range object instead. Also there are smarter ways to test if a value exists inside another range than a loop. That will at least safe you the second loop.

Comment: `Interior.ColorIndex` is a property of a range object, which is missing here.

Comment: I changed the code but it is filling all the cells green if they match or not.

Comment: Think about the logic of what you're doing. Every time a cell in E doesn't match one in A it will be shaded. You need to better describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: The actual column letters do not matter, I want to be able to interchange those but the goal is to lope through the columns and if the cells do not match highlight those.  Right now it is highlighting them all if they match or not.

Comment: One observation is `Dim DerLigA, DerLigB  As Long, i, j As Long` isnt doing what you think it is.  Right now its defining DerLigA as a variant.  Change it to `Dim DerLigA As Long, DerLigB  As Long, i As Long, j As Long`

Comment: Okay fixed the variables and I am still getting all the cells in column E highlighted even if they are different from column A.  Man this is frustrating I am not a coder but this can't be that hard I just want to compare two columns not next to each other and highlight the ones that do not match.

Comment: Is the requirement to compare (A2) to (E2)? and (A3) to (E3)? etc?  If so, then loose subscript "i" and make everything "j". .. ..  OR.. .. Is the requirement to also compare (A2) to (E3),  and (A2) to (E4), .....  which is what is happening now??

Answer (score 0):

If you change `If .Range("A" & i) = .Range("E" & j) Then` to `If .Range("A" & i) <> .Range("E" & j) Then` as per your statement you want to test if the values in the cells don't match;  Currently your code is looking to see if the values in the cells match.

```
Sub ColumnCompare()

Dim DerLigA As Long, DerLigB As Long, i As Long, j As Long


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Sheet1")

    DerLigA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    DerLigB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row


    For i = 2 To DerLigA
        For j = 2 To DerLigB
            If .Range("A" & i) <> .Range("E" & j) Then
                .Range("E" & j).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```